# Как "переконфигурировать" в xmlns неймспейсы и к ним линки в SOAP-ENV:Envelope перед Header?

Tags: php, soap, request, namespace, wsdl

Нужно поменять в request'е (запросе) ns1 и ns2 на wsse и wsa (WS-Security и WS-Addressing), а также добавить еще один неймспейс, сейчас отправляет это:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://xml.****.com/*******" 
xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

А надо перевести на такое:

```
<SOAP:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecuritysecext-
1.0.xsd"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurityutility-
1.0.xsd">
```

Пишу на PHP, в `__setSoapHeaders` передаю адекватные заголовки, формирую строку "явно", функция обращения - верная, WSDL - рабочий (во всяком случае у других работает).

Comment: Если у вас есть к этому доступ как к строке, то через str_replace() сделайте замену первой строки на вторую О_о

Comment: Отредактировал вам форматирование кода. Здесь стоило использовать кнопку `{}`, а не `<>` — вторая только для JS/HTML/CSS кода, который будет выполняться прямо в браузере.

Comment: Нету дело в том что(( Эта строка генерируется при передаче SoapClient-обьекта